# BufferedReader or Socket does not throw exception when telnet closes

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I have a problem where there is no IOException thrown when a Telnet client disconnects.

I used the server code from the following source:

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/Code/SocketThrdServer.java

From the given code, the server should terminate and display "Read Fail" when the client close. But it's not happening for Telnet or Putty (RAW connection). On the contrary, it works when I used the example Client given, it works perfectly.

I've also tried modifying the code so that readLine() doesn't block the I/O always, but using a timeout. However, it doesn't seem that it helped in detecting whether the Client has been disconnected.

```
    while (true) {
        try {
            client.setSoTimeout(1000);
            line = in.readLine();
            // Send data back to client
            out.println(line);
            textArea.append(line);

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            if(client.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("Client disconnected");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Read failed");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

Is there something missing from using Telnet or Raw Connection?

**Edit:** In addition to that, when I run 2 Clients, and then I close the first client, there would be no exception thrown from BufferedReader...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a graceful shutdown, there should be no IO Exception.
`in.readLine();` should return null in that case, a case your code should handle.

Comment: Okay, I guess that answer the point why. However, I'm curious why does a graceful close does not set the socket state to closed? This makes isClosed() ineffective because the socket still thinks it's not closed...

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly what isClosed() signifys, but a TCP connection only closed when *both* ends have closed the connection (or one end have reset it, sending a TCP RST). TCP connections can be in a half duplex state, where one end has closed its write direction, but the other end can still send data.

Comment: @Seeyabye There is no 'dial tone' in TCP so there is no way for one socket to know that the socket at the other end has been closed other than by attempting I/O on the connection. `isClosed()` and friends only tell you what you have done to your own socket, not what has happened to the connection.